# Overload +, - for sets in haskell

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

In python, I can add (union) and subtract (difference) sets with `+` and `-`. How would I set this up in Haskell? Would `(-) = Data.Set.difference` work? I tried it, but then I think regular subtraction with numbers got messed up.

Comment: `Set` implements `Monoid`, so you already do have an operator for set union, which is `<>`. `Prelude Data.Set Data.Monoid> fromList "abc" <> fromList "bcd" => fromList "abcd"`. There's also backslash-backslash for subtraction. The reason they aren't `+` and `-` have been detailed in the excellent answers below.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell places a few more restrictions on the overloading of numerical operators than Python does, there are rules and laws that must be followed in order to define them.  For example, you would also need to define `*` and `abs` to go with it.  Instead, use the operators already defined in `Data.Set`, namely `\\` for set difference, and there isn't one already define for union, but you could easy make your own alias, or you could use it as

```
set1 `union` set2
```

I recommend sticking with the already defined functions and operators, it'll make your code much more readable to anyone else that takes a look at it.  Feel free to introduce new operators that do more than just alias an existing function, although good practice says to do so sparingly still.

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing to do is, to put it a bit comically, very unhaskellic.  Haskellers generally adopt the following attitude:

- The same name or symbol should not be overloaded to mean two different things.

This means that all overloadable names or symbols (i.e., class operations) must have a consistent core meaning that all of their overloaded instances must respect.

In Haskell, the `(+)` and `(-)` operations are defined by [the `Num` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:7).  The docs aren't explicit about it, but to implement a class you must implement all of its methods, which includes things like `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` (the operation that converts any `Integer` into an instance of your class) and `abs :: Num a => a -> a` (take the absolute value of a number).

You can't implement the `Num` class for sets without profoundly abusing its meaning.  So don't do it.

Note that there are other classes that may be more suitable to what you're trying to do.  For example, there is [the `Monoid` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) that provides generic operations that are suitable for sets.  In fact, [the `Data.Set` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.0/docs/Data-Set.html) implements `Monoid` as union, so you can use the `mappend` function or `(<>)` operator to take the union of two sets generically (or the append of two lists, or many other things).

There is no obvious, popular class that the `Set.difference` operator would be an instance of, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

To define a Num instance for a type it would look like:

```
instance Num (Set a) where
  (+) = -- definition
  (-) = -- definition
  -- etc
```

If you merely define, at the top level:

```
(-) = -- definition
```

Then you are simply shadowing the `(-)` that comes from Num.

As [bheklilr says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537122/260584), Set is not a valid instance for Num because it cannot satisfy the ring laws. Haskell will not forbid you from defining the instance but it is a poor idea. People work with type classes by using their laws, so violating them results in incorrect programs.

Comment: This is why floating point representations shouldn't be `Num` instances.